# Pattern usage for increment / decrement React (Hooks)

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, react.js

When asked to increment / decrement a particular value I usually create specific functions to handle this functionality. Like this:

```
  const increaseQuantity = index => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];

    currentItems[index].quantity += 1;
    setStock(currentItems);
  };

  const decreaseQuantity = index => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];

    if (currentItems[index].quantity > 1) {
      currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;
      setStock(currentItems);
    }
  };
```

I like this approach because it clearly separates each action. Also, it only takes one single argument which keeps things simple.

But I can also create a single function, that does both things (increment or decrement), but it uses an additional parameter `action` as well as logic to perform the update:

```
  const manageQuantity = (index, action) => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];

    if (action === "increase") {
      currentItems[index].quantity += 1;
      setStock(currentItems);
    }

    if (currentItems[index].quantity > 1 && action === "decrease") {
      currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;
      setStock(currentItems);
    }
  };
```

I feel that the second pattern (single function) is more prone to error. Mainly because the the second argument is a (string).

Which is considered best practice and also follows some established (or well known) design pattern? Also, is one pattern more performant than the other?

Full functioning example below:

```js
const availableItems = [
  {
    name: "iPod Nano",
    capacity: "4GB",
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    name: "iPod Classic",
    capacity: "30GB",
    quantity: 2
  },
  {
    name: "iPod Mini",
    capacity: "4GB",
    quantity: 5
  }
];

function FirstApp() {
  const [stock, setStock] = React.useState(availableItems);

  const increaseQuantity = index => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];
    currentItems[index].quantity += 1;
    setStock(currentItems);
  };

  const decreaseQuantity = index => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];

    if (currentItems[index].quantity > 1) {
      currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;
      setStock(currentItems);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h2>FirstApp</h2>
      {JSON.stringify(stock)}
      <hr />

      {stock.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={item.name}>
          {item.name} | <button onClick={() => increaseQuantity(i)}>+</button>
          <button onClick={() => decreaseQuantity(i)}>-</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function SecondApp () {
  const [stock, setStock] = React.useState(availableItems);

  const increaseQuantity = index => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];
    currentItems[index].quantity += 1;
    setStock(currentItems);
  };

  const decreaseQuantity = index => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];

    if (currentItems[index].quantity > 1) {
      currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;
      setStock(currentItems);
    }
  };

  const manageQuantity = (index, action) => {
    const currentItems = [...stock];
    if (action === "increase") {
      currentItems[index].quantity += 1;
      setStock(currentItems);
    }

    if (currentItems[index].quantity > 1 && action === "decrease") {
      currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;
      setStock(currentItems);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h2>SecondApp</h2>
      {JSON.stringify(stock)}
      <hr />

      {stock.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={item.name}>
          {item.name} |{" "}
          <button onClick={() => manageQuantity(i, "increase")}>+</button>
          <button onClick={() => manageQuantity(i, "decrease")}>-</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FirstApp />
      <SecondApp />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.app {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, where we review working code and provide suggestions on how that code can be improved. This question without the functioning snippet is off-topic.Rather than hiding the snippet I would leave it fully open all the time.

Comment: The functioning snippet is under "Show code snippet" @pacmaninbw

Comment: Please see our [guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for future reference. Especially any part about context.

Comment: `currentItems[index].quantity += 1` mutates the state. `const currentItems = [...stock]` only creates a shallow copy of the array.

Comment: I'm not mutating the state @adiga, I'm making a copy of the state using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). I then make the change and update the state. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) for details.

Comment: @JuanMarco spread syntax creates a copy of the array. The objects inside it are still the same in the copy and the original array.

Comment: @JuanMarco spread only makes a *shallow* copy. Only works if the array is composed entirely of primitives like strings, numbers or booleans. You have an array of objects, so it won't do a deep copy.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Implementation 1

```
const increaseQuantity = index => {
  const currentItems = [...stock];

  currentItems[index].quantity += 1;
  setStock(currentItems);
};

const decreaseQuantity = index => {
  const currentItems = [...stock];

  if (currentItems[index].quantity > 1) {
    currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;
    setStock(currentItems);
  }
};
```

### Issues

- `currentItems[index].quantity += 1;` and `currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;` are state mutations.
- Any computed state updates should use functional state updates and compute the next state from the current state. If for any reason more than a single `increaseQuantity` or `decreaseQuantity` is queued within a single render cycle only one gets applied. Similarly, if both a `increaseQuantity` *and* `decreaseQuantity` are enqueued, one would expect the net gain to be zero, but the last one enqueued is the one applied, so the net gain won't be zero.

### Solution

- Use a functional update
- Correctly compute next state

Suggestions

```
const increaseQuantity = index => {
  setStock(stock =>
    stock.map((el, i) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            ...el,
            quantity: el.quantity + 1
          }
        : el
    )
  );
};

const decreaseQuantity = index => {
  setStock(stock =>
    stock.map((el, i) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            ...el,
            quantity: el.quantity - el.quantity > 1 ? 1 : 0,
            // or
            // quantity: Math.max(0, el.quantity - 1),
          }
        : el
    )
  );
};
```

## Implementation 2

```
const manageQuantity = (index, action) => {
  const currentItems = [...stock];

  if (action === "increase") {
    currentItems[index].quantity += 1;
    setStock(currentItems);
  }

  if (currentItems[index].quantity > 1 && action === "decrease") {
    currentItems[index].quantity -= 1;
    setStock(currentItems);
  }
};
```

### Issues

- Suffers the same state mutation issue previously mentioned.
- More of a design pattern issue, but you've effectively encoded most of a reducer function.

### Solution 1

- Apply same fixes as implementation 1
- Reduce code duplication in function

Suggestions

```
const manageQuantity = (index, action) => {
  setStock(stock =>
    stock.map((el, i) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            ...el,
            quantity:
              el.quantity + action === "increment"
                ? 1
                : el.quantity > 1
                ? -1
                : 0
            // or
            // quantity: Math.max(0, el.quantity + action === "increment" ? 1 : -1)
          }
        : el
    )
  );
};
```

### Solution 2

- Apply same fixes as implementation 1
- Concert to [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) react hook

Suggestions

Create action types & creator, and a reducer function.

```
const ACTIONS_TYPE = {
  INCREMENT: 'INCREMENT',
  DECREMENT: 'DECREMENT',
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTIONS_TYPE.INCREMENT:
      return state.map((el, i) => i === action.index ? {
        ...el,
        quantity: el.quantity + 1,
      } : el);

    case ACTIONS_TYPE.DECREMENT:
      return state.map((el, i) => i === action.index ? {
        ...el,
        quantity: Math.max(0, el.quantity - 1),
      } : el);

    default:
      return state;
  };
};

const increment = index => ({
  type: ACTIONS_TYPE.INCREMENT,
  index,
});

const decrement = index => ({
  type: ACTIONS_TYPE.DECREMENT,
  index,
});
```

Use in component

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const incrementQuantity = () => index => dispatch(increment(index));
const decrementQuantity = () => index => dispatch(decrement(index));

...

...onClick={incrementQuantity(index)}...
```

***Notice***:

- Action types are defined as an ENUM so when used in code the likelihood of typos is reduced since the string text isn't used directly.
- Like its redux big brother, it is a bit boiler-plately, but abstracts and isolates the state computation into a reducer pure function. IMO this improves the readability of the code using it.
- It still applies the pattern of using the current state and some input to compute the next state, still always a returning a new state object.

## TL;DR

Complexity is similar in both approaches so it really comes down to familiarity. The former is close to the normal component state pattern while the latter resembles a portion of the redux pattern. One isn't necessarily better than the other, though I'd say for simple state the `useState` and update functions may be easier to grok for juniors joining your team than the `useReducer` which works well for more complex state shapes.

Lessons Learned

1. Don't mutate state, use shallow copies of state (and sub-state) and update when necessary.
2. Use functional state updates to ensure multiple state updates enqueued within the same render cycle correctly compute next state from previous state.

Comment: When you said "If for any reason more than a single `increaseQuantity` or `increaseQuantity`"
Didn't you mean `increaseQuantity` and `decreaseQuantity`?

Comment: @JuanMarco Yes, I certainly did mean that, thanks. (*copy/paste error*) I've updated answer. Sorry if that caused any confusion.